# https security certificate not trusted error on mobile via openshift server

Tags: android, ssl, https, openshift

I'm starting an app on openshift. I've purchased comodo positive ssl from namecheap and followed the instructions to install on openshift. It works fine on desktop browsers but i get the following "not trusted" error on android browsers. I have not tried IOS.

i uploaded following files to openshift:

- stylistcity_com.crt
- server.key

Other files i have that were not used include:

- server.csr
- server.pass.key
- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- PositiveSSLCA2.crt

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

[image: matches domain]

[image: Cert chain]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @stenwt from the openshift irc channel, It finally work. Here is what i did.

```
cat mycert.crt cacert.ca > myapp.pem; rhc alias update-cert appname www.domain.com --certificate myapp.pem --private-key myapp.key --passphrase 'mypass'
```

Comment: Thanks man. It's really simple but I've been trying for hours and it didn't work. The two commands of yours worked like a charm. : )

Comment: For those who need more details: instead of only uploading your domain certificate you have to create a .pem file which contains your domain certificate as well as your root CA (1) and intermediate CA certificates (2). Simply open Notepad, copy paste your domain certificate first, after that your root CA certificate, then your intermediate certificates. Save as myapp.pem and upload to openshift together with the private key. Then mobile browsers will accept the connection as secure as well.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. I tried uploading the files through the web interface and even though OpenShift has a field to upload the cert-chain separately only combining the cert and the cert-chain in one file and uploading it as the cert solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the intermediate certificate(s) (the other *.crt) too, because otherwise the browser is not able to verify the certificate chain up to the builtin trusted CA. The only reason that the verification with the desktop browsers succeed is because you already visited sites which use the same intermediate certificates and the browser cached them. If you would use a fresh browser setup (or a new profile with firefox) verification would there fail too.

Comment: Thanks. I now have a better understanding. I installed the chain certs but its still not working. At this point i probably need to speak to someone from openshift. Unfortunately i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The certificate is still messed up. While the chain is OK now, the certificate when accessing www.stylistcity.com is for *.rhcloud.com, e.g. the redhat cloud. Thus it does not match the hostname and even a desktop browser should now refuse the connection.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? I uploaded screenshots from www.sslchecker.com. It shows that it the domain matches and the chain is is not installed

Comment: Sorry, my fault and a strange server setup: stylistcity.com and www.stylistcity.com resolve to different hosts, but the certificate at www.stylistcity.com claims to be for stylistcity.com too. As you will also note with sslchecker or sslabs.com - the chain is still not correctly set up, e.g. the intermediate certificates you got are still missing.

Comment: Yes because I'm using openshift which Is a  paas similar to heroku, I can only point subdomains to it. So I have my rRoot domain redirecting to the www subdomain. The only way I see to install the chain Is to upload a file via the web interface. However uploading seems to do nothing. There's no way to contact openshift unless I get their silver plan

Answer (score 0):

Had a bit of trouble with the method that worked for OP. For PositiveSSL, on OpenShift, this worked for me:

```
cat mydomain_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
rhc alias update-cert myappname www.mydomain.com --certificate ssl-bundle.crt --private-key mydomain_com.key --passphrase 'mypassphrase'
```

Replace *mydomain_com.crt* with your main domain cert from Comodo
Replace *myappname* with your OpenShift app name
Replace *www.mydomain.com* with your domain alias (the one on OpenShift for your app)
Replace *mydomain_com.key* with the filename for your private key
Replace *mypassphrase* with your SSL passphrase

Answer (score 0):

I've opened certificate.ca.crt and certificate.crt, with conTEXT editor,
I copied the contents of certificate.crt and have pasted to the principle of certificate.ca.crt and have saved as certificate.pem, after I've uploaded to OpenShift web console, in SSL certificate *, the first box. Fixed !!