# OpenShift: SSLCertificateChainFile not evaluated

Tags: ssl-certificate, openshift

I've uploaded the SSL Certificate, the SSL Certificate Chain and the Certificate Private Key to my OpenShift app alias, but apparently, the SSL Certificate Chain fiel is not being properly set. When I check here: https://www.digicert.com/help/index.htm?host=devassistant.org - it says:

```
Tip: It looks like this server is running Apache. In most cases, solving this problem is as simple as adding "SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt" to your apache configuration file after/near your SSLCertificateFile line.
```

But obviously I cannot do that. What should I do now?

Note: I've previously uploaded the SSL Certificate and the Certificate Private Key without the SSL Certificate Chain and now I deleted the certficate and reuploaded with the SSL Certificate Chain - might that cause the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [https security certificate not trusted error on mobile via openshift server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713422/https-security-certificate-not-trusted-error-on-mobile-via-openshift-server)

Comment: Yes that was it. I've merged the two certificates to one file and upload it just as SSL Certificate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The chain file must be uploaded **initially**, otherwise OpenShift won't handle it correctly: you'll get a "sec_error_unkown_issuer" warning in Firefox.

Credits go to [Robin](https://robinwinslow.co.uk/2014/08/26/host-your-site-with-https-for-free/).

Comment: Thanks you! After hours of work this was the solution. Deleting the alias and creating it again made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open Notepad, copy paste your domain certificate first, after that your root CA certificate, then your intermediate certificates. Save as myapp.pem and upload to openshift together with the private key. Then mobile browsers will accept the connection as secure as well.